# Design a beam that is straightened with force on one end

Tags: structural-beam

From [here](https://www.quora.com/Bend-a-beam-heavily-Now-freeze-that-geometrical-state-and-get-rid-of-any-tensions-Apply-the-opposite-force-Does-it-have-the-same-horizontal-shape-of-the-beginning), I read that if you have a straight beam, bend it with force at one end, and then create a beam with the resulting curvature, the equal and opposite force *won't* make a straight beam.

- What is the shape of a curved beam that will become straight given a point force on the end?

Assume the cross section is rectangular.

Comment: The prestressed beam design problem belongs into mechanical engineering.